# Loading two instances of a shared library

Tags: c, windows, linux, dll

For a test I'd like to load two instances of a shared library from an application. The code in the library provides an API but it does not allow me to initialize two (or more) instances of the library because some of the functions rely on static variables..

I'm currently writing unit-tests for this lib, and I'd like to have two instances because that would simplify my tests a lot.

The library doesn't get linked into the program. Instead I load it directly using LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress (or dlopen/dlsym on linux). To distinguish the two libraries I could simply use different names for the function-pointers I'm loading...

Here are the questions:

- Is it possible to load such a library twice? E.g. All loaded instances of the library should get their own data-segment and don't influence each other.
- If so: Is this portable for windows and linux?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can load a library twice, in theory, if it's compiled as position-independent code (`-fPIC`).

On some Unices, you can then `dlopen` the library twice if your loader has an `RTLD_PRIVATE` flag, or by having two "different" copies of the library with the same symbols (put it at two different paths, otherwise it will just return the first file handle), and opening them each with `RTLD_LOCAL`.

I don't know anything about Windows shared libraries.  It may not even be possible.

Comment: Everything is compiled with -fPIC of course.. Didn't knew about RTLD_PRIVATE. After a man-session it looks exactly what I want - for linux at last. I may open a separate question for windows.

Answer (score 3):

On windows at least, you could just rename the library, and load both of them.

Comment: Windows will load multiple instances of the same DLL if you use full paths; i.e. "C:\path1\test.dll", "C:\path2\test.dll", etc.  If you don't want to create separate directories then renaming is the only other approach.