# Loading two instances of a shared library without RTLD_PRIVATE or multiple copies

Tags: c++, gcc, fortran, shared-libraries, fortran-common-block

In C++ I need to run multiple instances of legacy FORTRAN libraries (over which I have no control) which use COMMON BLOCK variables. I can successfully do this following the prescription of [Question 3433522](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433522/loading-two-instances-of-a-shared-library), where I create 2 physical copies of the library, and load these at run-time using `dlopen` (see example code below).

However, I would like avoid having to create two physical copies of the library, as it can be rather large. As suggested in [Question 3433522](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433522/loading-two-instances-of-a-shared-library), using `RTLD_PRIVATE` would work, but this is not available (as far as I can tell) in `libgc` with GCC. I've also investigated using `RTLD_DEEPBIND` rather than `RTLD_LOCAL` but this makes no difference. Any idea how this could be accomplished using GCC?

My example code is as follows:

1. Makefile

   ```
   libgen.so: gen.f
       gfortran -Wall -shared -fPIC -o $@ $<

   libgen%.so: libgen.so
       cp $< $@

   run: run.cpp libgen1.so libgen2.so
       g++ -Wall -o $@ $< -L. -ldl
   ```
2. gen.f

   ```
   C*********************************************************************

   C...GENDATA
   C...Common block of data. 
         BLOCK DATA
         INTEGER NEVENT
         COMMON/GENDATA/NEVENT
         DATA NEVENT/0/
         END

   C*********************************************************************

   C...EVENT
   C...Simple example routine that produces an "event".

         SUBROUTINE GENERATE()
         INTEGER NEVENT
         COMMON/GENDATA/NEVENT
         NEVENT = NEVENT + 1
         PRINT *, NEVENT
         RETURN
         END
   ```
3. run.cpp

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <dlfcn.h>
   using namespace std;

   //==========================================================================

   // Methods to load and close dynamic libraries.

   //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

   // Load a symbol from a library.

   typedef void (*Symbol)();
   Symbol libSym(void *&lib, string libName, string symName) {

     Symbol sym(0);
     const char* error(0);

     // Load the library, if not loaded.
     if (!lib) {
       lib = dlopen(libName.c_str(), RTLD_NOW | RTLD_LOCAL);
       error = dlerror();
     }
     if (error) {
       cerr << "Error from libSym: " + string(error) + "\n";
       return sym;
     }
     dlerror();

     // Load the symbol.
     sym = (Symbol)dlsym(lib, symName.c_str());
     error = dlerror();
     if (error) cerr << "Error from libSym: " + string(error) + "\n";
     dlerror();
     return sym;

   }

   //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

   // Close a library.

   void libClose(void *&lib) {
     if (lib) {dlclose(lib); dlerror();}
   }

   //==========================================================================

   // The main program.

   //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

   int main() {

     // Load libraries.
     void *libgen1(0), *libgen2(0);
     cout << "Loading library 1.\n";
     void (*generate1)();
     generate1 = libSym(libgen1, "./libgen1.so", "generate_");
     if (!libgen1) return 1;
     cout << "Loading library 2.\n";
     void (*generate2)();
     generate2 = libSym(libgen2, "./libgen2.so", "generate_");
     if (!libgen2) return 1;

     // Generate events.
     cout << "Generating 1.\n";
     (*generate1)();
     cout << "Generating 1.\n";
     (*generate1)();
     cout << "Generating 2.\n";
     (*generate2)();

     // Close the libraries.
     libClose(libgen1);
     libClose(libgen2);
     return 0;

   }
   ```

Comment: Why you have no control if you have the source?

Comment: I don't have the source, the above is just a simplified example.

Comment: Do they ship/Can you get static version of the library?

Comment: Yes, I think it should be possible to obtain static versions of the libraries.