# Loading two dynamic library instances in Python

Tags: python, ctypes, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have a program written in Fortran and compiled (with -fPIC) as a dynamic library. I load with CDLL in Python to perform some numerical calculations. The library uses internal persistent memory (in modules) to save intermediate values. I work both on Windows and Linux (with a .dll and an .so, respectively). The dynamic library is packaged inside the Python module and installed in a lib subdirectory.

If I run two different Python scripts that load the dynamic library on the same computer, would they get a separate internal memory or will they access the same one (thus, corrupting the results)?

How would this be affected if I:

- Load them inside a different multiprocessing instance
- Load them inside a different multithreading instance
- Load them in two different Jupyter notebooks with different kernel
- Run them in different Python virtual environments

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3433522/801468). However, since the dynamic library is included in the Python module, I want to avoid having to rename and move around files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I run two different Python scripts that load the dynamic library on the same computer, would they get a separate internal memory or will they access the same one (thus, corrupting the results)?

- The same library can only be loaded **once**; more precisely as long as you try to load a library with the same path it gets only loaded once in the process.

  - Now supposing that you load a library, copy / paste that library elsewhere, rename it and try to load the copy then it gets loaded twice.
- As for the memory used by the same library loaded multiple times, as you get only one library loaded, there's no corruption. If you load a copy of it, then each of those library gets its own memory allocations.

> Load them inside a different multiprocessing instance

No problems. multiprocessing uses different processes and different processes can't overwrite anything into another process address space (unless **explicitly** asked for it).

> Load them inside a different multithreading instance

You'll only be able to load one instance of the library. That being said as you only have one instance of the library, technically **and depending on the library**, a call to a function might overwrite the previous internal state of the library. It heavily depends if the library can be used in a multi-threading context.

As you said the library keeps an internal state, each call to a function has a chance to overwrite / change the previous internal state (depending on the effects of the called function on the internal state).

> Load them in two different Jupyter notebooks with different kernel

Depends if the two notebooks are using two different instance of the interpreter or not.

- If it's the same interpreter running two notebooks, then you only have one instance of your library loaded by the interpreter.
- Different interpreters: two processes -> two libraries with each its own separated state.

> Run them in different Python virtual environments

Different virtual environments uses different processes.

Comment: Amazing, exactly what I was looking for! Saved me hours of testing!